# Read json data using getjson

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, attributes, getjson

I have a json file:

```
{
  "bible" : {
    "@attributes" : {
      "translation" : "ASV"
    },
    "testament" : [
      {
        "@attributes" : {
          "name" : "Old"
        },
        "book" : [
          {
            "@attributes" : {
              "name" : "Genesis"
            }
          },
          {
            "@attributes" : {
              "name" : "Exodus"
            }
          },
          {
            "@attributes" : {
              "name" : "Leviticus"
            }
          },
          {
            "@attributes" : {
              "name" : "Numbers"
            }
          },
          {
            "@attributes" : {
              "name" : "Deuteronomy"
            }
          },
          {
            "@attributes" : {
              "name" : "Joshua"
            }
          },
          {
            "@attributes" : {
              "name" : "Judges"
            }
          },
          {
            "@attributes" : {
              "name" : "Ruth"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using code to read it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("asv/index.json", function(json) {
       alert("JSON Data: " + json.bible.testament[1].name);
     });
});
```

But this gives me undefined. Please let me know how to read book names. Also @attributes are what for?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 $.getJSON('asv/index.json', 
function(json) {
    $.each(json.bible.testament[0].book,  // $.each() looping on each books
    function(i, value) {
        console.log(value['@attributes'].name);  // here you get the name of books
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong object path to your data. I recommend that you paste your json data into a viewer to make it easier to see what you need to get. Try http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ for example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("asv/index.json", function(json) {
        alert(json.bible.testament[0]['@attributes'].name);
        alert(json.bible.testament[0].book[0]['@attributes'].name);
    });
});
</script>
```

That works for me. Notice how you don't have any `testament[1]` index, only `testament[0]`.

The @attributes part seems to be something the script that generates the JSON is creating, nothing you need to use JSON per say. I would remove it if I had access to the JSON-creating script, but perhaps it is used in some system that you do not see.

Answer (score 0):

`json.bible.testament[1].name` is undefined.

try `json.bible.testament[1]['@attributes'].name`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a browser that supports console.log (Firefox for example) you can do a 'console.log(json)' and look at the structure.
You can access names like that:

json.bible.testament[0].book[0]['@attributes'].name
json.bible.testament[0].book[1]['@attributes'].name
...